# Unable to clean up <none> repository

Tags: docker

I tried to clean those repository with the command

`sudo docker rmi -f $(docker images -a | grep "<none>" | awk "{print \$3}"`

it should be work by `-f` option but gave me

```
Error response from daemon: Conflict, 58dc8b35c567 wasn't deleted
Error response from daemon: Conflict, 1ca48c1cbec5 wasn't deleted
Error response from daemon: Conflict, 0f8b62ff7034 wasn't deleted
.
.(about 30 lines)
.
Error response from daemon: Conflict, 1ffad67b1f13 wasn't deleted
Error response from daemon: Conflict, ef2704e74ecc wasn't deleted
FATA[0001] Error: failed to remove one or more images
```

Same issue even i try delete single images

command:`sudo docker rmi -f ef2704e74ecc`

response:
`Error response from daemon: Conflict, ef2704e74ecc wasn't deleted
FATA[0000] Error: failed to remove one or more images`

Comment: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1530. Check if the images are associated with multiple repos

Comment: it seems different issue also make some conflicts. In my case, those `Image ID` isn't duplicate to each other, and <none> tag is unable to use.

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar issue with docker 1.7-1.9: [issue 12487](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12487)

It could be linked [to a bad container](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/71a499022904e1da074ded3e1ed874c1b75ccf23) (fixed in docker 1.8)

As commented is [issue 11154](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/11154#issuecomment-77173952), try cleaning up dangling images first:

> check out `docker rmi $(docker images -q --filter dangling=true)` that deletes any images that are "dangling" (are not being used by any parent image)

If it is not linked to a container, the only "workaround" then was to nuke everything and restart docker.

```
$ rm -rf /var/lib/docker
$ systemctl restart docker
```

Of course, this is a last resort workaround, make sure you don't have any local data (especially in `/var/lib/docker/volumes`) that you would need to save/backup first.

Comment: Yes, I tried the "workaround" about 2hour ago. It's not a good solution surely, but really work. 

Btw, my docker is installed via `apt-get install docker.io` , both Client/Server version are 1.6.2.

Comment: @TomN 1.6.2, that would explain it: this seems ancient. Can you upgrade?